# Como adicionar caracteres a um tipo de teclado nativo do iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, teclado

Cenário: Em uma tela do app, o usuário devera informar um tipo de dado que é somente de números para realizar uma busca. Para evitar que use texto, configurei um teclado para o tipo: Number Pad. Porém preciso que apareça juntos aos números outros caracteres, no caso o hífen ( - ) e o ponto-final ( . ).

Alguém tem idéia de como posso fazer isso?.

Tive a idéia de pelo menos instanciar uma classe do `UITextFiled` e editar o tipo de teclado que aparece para ele.

Abaixo está uma imagem de com está e de como pretendo que fique:

[image: Estado Atual]

[image: Como preciso que fique]

Mas alguém se alguém puder me orientar ficarei grato!

Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Existe uma opção no `UITextField` com teclado para números e pontuações, mas é o teclado inteiro, apenas altera a visualização inicial assim que ele é exibido.

De qualquer forma, você pode utilizar uma validação no método abaixo disponível delegate `UITextFieldDelegate`. Faça algo assim:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if (textField == self.inputTest) {
        NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789.-"] invertedSet];
        NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

        return [string isEqualToString:filtered];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Assim você irá restringir o campo, que neste meu exemplo é o **inputTest**, para aceitar somente números, pontos e hifens.

Veja se isso te atende.

Comment: Vou colocar uma imagem pra ilustrar melhor a idéia de como está e de como seria o teclado que quero

Comment: Entendi. Mas se você realmente precisa de um teclado somente com os caracteres possíveis, só é possível incluindo uma view fora do teclado, igual ao que vemos em navegadores por exemplo. Ou criando seu próprio teclado, seja através do novo recurso do iOS 8 ou no `inputView` do campo.

Comment: Puts to lascado rs vou ver se tem alguma projeto pra isso na net